# lastModified returns "Invalid Date"

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to display the last updated time of a file (not my html file, another file).

HTML:

```
<p>Last updated: <span id="lastUpdate"></span></p>
```

JavaScript:

```
var file = 'data/myFile.csv';
var modifiedTime = new Date(file.lastModified);
document.getElementById('lastUpdate').innerHTML = modifiedTime;
```

When I run it, it just displays the following; (with no errors in the console)

> Last updated: Invalid Date

---

I'm obviously missing something, probably something small.

#### Edit:

My files are setup like below:

```
site/index.html
site/data/myFile.csv
site/js/lastUpdate.js
```

Comment: file is a string here, not an actual file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to retrieve the last modified date of a file using Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2313620/is-it-possible-to-retrieve-the-last-modified-date-of-a-file-using-javascript)

Comment: Is that your actual code?

Comment: @epascarello yes

Comment: okay so where does this file actually exists since all you really have is a string in your current code

Comment: @epascarello I updated my post

Answer (score -1):

Yes - when you declare variable

```
var file = 'data/myFile.csv'
```

in `file` variable you have only file path - not file content (to read it you can use [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)). The second thing-  when you read file content - then you should parse it - to read proper csv column