# Is it possible to get the lastModified date of a file hosted on the server?

Tags: javascript, html

With the code below I'm able to read, and log to the console, the contents of a file (myfile.txt) hosted on-line on the same folder/server as the HTML page with such code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<script>

async function doIt()
{
  let response = await fetch("myfile.txt", {cache: "no-store"});
  let contents = await response.text();
  console.log(contents);
}
    doIt();

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

My problem is that instead of the file contents I want to log the date/time when such file (myfile.txt) was last modified and I can't find the way to do it.

What am I missing? Would it be possible? How?

Many thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: There is a header that can give this information Last-modified, what server are you using?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2313620/is-it-possible-to-retrieve-the-last-modified-date-of-a-file-using-javascript

Comment: @peterduffy, I'm using an Italian service provider: www.aruba.it. Would the functionality I'm trying to achieve be "server dependent"? Thanks and regards

Comment: @Woodsy, many thanks for your input! I've tried the fetch method as suggested by FutureBoy and it works fine.